# Write html anchor text (with name / value pair) to a string

Tags: c#, string, linq

I think I can't see the forest for the trees here. I want to write a string. Using Linq to SQL I have created a result and I'm looping through it to dynamically write anchor tags.

But, the code is producing this:

```
<a 45="" href="ADappointment.aspx?openingid">My person booked< /a >
```

I want:

```
<a href="ADappointment.aspx?openingid=45">My person booked< /a >
```

Here's what I'm doing:

```
foreach (var anOpening in results)
  string sFlag = @"";
  sFlag = @"<td><a href=""ADappointment.aspx?openingid=""" + anOpening.OpeningId + ">" + patient.FirstName + " " + patient.LastName + " accepted </a></td>";
```

...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have quotes in your href which the browser doesnt expect.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've been Googling around how to do this and that's as close as I've gotten. But it's wrong. I've tried without the '@' and used a backslash but I'm still doing something wrong. Do you know how to create these types of strings?

Comment: Try escaping the extra quotes `\""+`.

Answer (score 0):

You have quotes in your href value the browser doesnt expect.. so it is rendering it completely incorrectly.

You are producing this:

`href="urlhere.aspx?id="99""`

Note the quotes around the ID. Remove those from your code. You want something like this:

```
sFlag = @"<td><a href=""ADappointment.aspx?openingid=" + anOpening.OpeningId + """>" + /* the rest here */
```

Ideally you would use a library to do this. There is a TagBuilder class in the MVC assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Format` to clearly format string.

```
foreach (var anOpening in results)
{
    var sFlag = String.Format(@"<td><a href=""ADappointment.aspx?openingid={0}"">{1} {2} accepted </a></td>", anOpening.OpeningId, patient.FirstName, patient.LastName);
}
```